In Lua, is it possible to do delayed expansion like you can in batch script?
Lets say I have multiple arrays:
arr1 = {1,2}
arr2 = {3,4,5}
arr3 = {6,7,8,9}

and I want to use something like this to randomly pick something from one of them:
local randomPick = 1
    if #array > 1 then
        repeat
            randomPick = RNG:NextInteger(1, #array)
        until randomPick ~= lastPick
        lastPick = randomPick
    end

would it be possible for me to replace the #array in the code with a variable? or is that not possible in Lua? I ask mainly because I know you can do it in batch, so I thought maybe it would be here too.
Thanks in advance!

Well, keep in mind that #table is not exactly the element count of that table. For example print( #{1,nil,2,nil}) will not display 2, nor 4. It will display 1, despite having 2 clear non-null elements in it. That's just to make sure we're all clear on what the code does, before we start using it. As for your request, what are the rules of lastPick? For example your arrays are not sharing item values. Are you also asking how to also retain the last returned value of each table? (else lastPick makes little sense, unless you're sure you'll use the same table consecutively)

As for using a variable to "reuse" a table, yes, it's possible, just pass it as a parameter.

I'm not sure how you understand delayed expansion. In lua the value of variables are always up-to-date. Can you show a batch script to demonstrate your purpose?

You are just getting the random item number, but want the value. You're missing the [] operator. Also, read my comment regarding # to know its limitations. In most cases you can use that, of course. (I mostly wrote it so that you know what to expect if you have strange behaviours when different values get null-ed.
This is what you're probably looking for:
local math = require "math"

arr1 = {1, 2}
arr2 = {3, 4, 5}
arr3 = {6, 7, 8, 9}

function randomize(array)
    return array[math.random(1, #array)]
end

print(randomize(arr1))
print(randomize(arr2))
print(randomize(arr3))

There is no NextInteger function or a default RNG library, so you're probably using roblox. In that case, use the random library from roblox instead of LUA's default math in my example. The params are the same: min and max.
As for the lastPick, you'll need a separate logic for that if you want to make sure the last random number is distinct and dedicated for each table. But to pass by reference as a pseudo-out parameter, you'll need to convert it to a table:
local math = require "math"

local arr1 = {1, 2}
local arr2 = {3, 4, 5}
local arr3 = {6, 7, 8, 9}

local lastPickArr1 = {}
local lastPickArr2 = {}
local lastPickArr3 = {}

function randomize(array, lastPick)
    local randomPick

    repeat
        randomPick = array[math.random(1, #array)]
    until randomPick ~= lastPick[0]
    
    lastPick[0] = randomPick
    
    return randomPick
end

print(randomize(arr1, lastPickArr1))
print("last: " .. lastPickArr1[0])
print(randomize(arr2, lastPickArr2))
print( lastPickArr2[0])
print(randomize(arr3, lastPickArr3))
print( lastPickArr3[0])
print(randomize(arr1, lastPickArr1))
print("last: " .. lastPickArr1[0])
print(randomize(arr1, lastPickArr1))
print("last: " .. lastPickArr1[0])
print(randomize(arr1, lastPickArr1))
print("last: " .. lastPickArr1[0])
print(randomize(arr1, lastPickArr1))
print("last: " .. lastPickArr1[0])
print(randomize(arr1, lastPickArr1))
print("last: " .. lastPickArr1[0])
print(randomize(arr1, lastPickArr1))
print("last: " .. lastPickArr1[0])
print(randomize(arr1, lastPickArr1))
print("last: " .. lastPickArr1[0])
print(randomize(arr1, lastPickArr1))
print("last: " .. lastPickArr1[0])
print(randomize(arr1, lastPickArr1))
print("last: " .. lastPickArr1[0])
print(randomize(arr1, lastPickArr1))
print("last: " .. lastPickArr1[0])

Output:

2
last: 2
4
4
9
9
1
last: 1
2
last: 2
1
last: 1
2
last: 2
1
last: 1
2
last: 2
1
last: 1
2
last: 2
1
last: 1
2
last: 2
[Execution complete with exit code 0]

Of course there are better ways to refactor this. I am just showing you a PoC.
Also try to use local variables and functions as much as possible as opposed to global ones for best performance. You can also add local "pointers" to global functions and use them for some performance gain.
If you're wondering why I used tables for the local lastPick, it's because primitives are passed by value. So using regular ints would only update their value inside the function, but when it left its scope they'd be nil again. Objects, on the other hand, are passed by reference and you can use that as a trick to get pseudo-out parameter behavior. Of course, as with any reference passing, be aware of its implications and use wisely
(no, I don't mean performance wise, as pass-by-reference should always be faster, but rather, that it modifies the original so any "temporary" change that you use and forget to delete, might cause bugs, so be careful what experiments you do as you might end up debugging for hours for one simple assignment operation or hardcoding you did as a test, but forgot to remove/update)
Also, in order to ensure no repetition (or maybe to force repetition for tests), remember to seed the random once on app initialization, depending on your use-case. According ot the docs, roblox applies one if you didn't.
For the default math lib, you'd use math.randomseed(x), for roblox, you'd use new.
For example: local initializedRNG = Random.new(os.clock() * 1000). Using the os library. Then you can use that initiated RNG. In the case of initiatialized seeds in roblox, they are used when creating a new Random object, meaning, if you use multiple you'd have random seeds (or seeding once will not apply the same seed if you instantiate a new one without a seed). As I said, it depends on your use-case, as the topic of seeding random libraries in general can turn into long discussions by themselves. And as said, that is just about seeding. RNG and PRNG by themselves would be even longer discussions.

I couldn't think of the name at the time, but what I meant to ask was, is it possible to do delayed expansion in Lua like you can do in batch? (i'll edit the question)

@TheLemon27 I think you're coming dangerously close to an XY problem. What is it exactly you are trying to achieve? According to the original question, my answer does what you initially asked. Let's break it down to a real use-case of yours. Don't ask what is possible in lua right away, first say what you need, what needs to happen and why. Then we see what is possible using lua or what workarounds there are. This is the proper approach to avoid the XY problem. Else you'll find yourself asking the wrong question and getting answers you don't need.

I ended up coming up with a very hackneyed solution, but yeah I agree that did sound like an XY problem. When I read your response initially, I saw that you mentioned I was grabbing the position of the instead of the value, and that that was the problem, but I knew that part of the code was working. So I tried to explain the question better. All I was looking for was a more compact way of changing target of an if loop each time it runs, with what I was working on as example. Also yes, I'm using roblox. I didn't know how different they were, so I thought labelling it Lua would be enough, sorry.

As advice, if you're using a third party library, framework, workflow or environment, it is better to label it as well. So lua is the language, but the libraries are those of roblox.  In your case there was not much difference but the function name did surprise me. If you need help with it more, update the question and we'll see how we can go from there. Else, if you think my answer helped you, upvote the answer. Normally also mark as accepted if it fixed your issue, but it was more an XY so it didn't in this case I guess.

As I said, if you need to focus on an actual solution, rephrase the question with the workflow you need (to quote myself "first say what you need, what needs to happen and why"), else, the answer focused on the initial question which was not what you actually wanted (although it did fix your value problem). If what you want is more complex and different though, you'll need to ask a new question. As you're new to the community, also read How do I ask a good question as reference.
